# Finding Harmonic Conjugate

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have a simple harmonic function $u(x,y) = x^2 - y^2 +2xy$ and wish to find its harmonic conjugate.

To find a harmonic conjugate $v$ of $u$, we must have 
$$
u_x(x,y) =v_y(x,y)
$$
and
$$
u_y(x,y) = -v_x(x,y)
$$
From the first we have $v_y= u_x = 2x+2y \implies v = \int (2x+2y)dy = 2xy +y^2 + C(x)$. It now follows from the second equation that 
$$
2(x-y) = -v_x =\implies -2(x-y) = v_x \implies v = 2xy-xy^2 + C(y)
$$
Therefore, we have 
$$
2y +y^2 + C(x) =  2xy-xy^2 + C(y)
$$

How do I solve for $C(x)$ and $C(y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that You started as

$$ v_y= u_x = 2x+2y \implies v = 2xy +y^2 +C(x) $$

To determine $C(x)$ we have

$$ v_x = 2y+0 + C'(x)  $$

then use $v_x=-u_y$ to find $C(x)$ by solving the first order differential equation.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you. I was able to solve it before the others had posted so since your answer was the one which lead me to solve the question I will choose yours as the Accepted Answer.

Comment: @ComplexOh: You are welcome.

Comment: If I were to do it the other way and find $C(y)$ instead, should I arrive at the same answer?

Comment: @ComplexOh: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to solving exact ODE's. If we have:

$$ u = x^2 - y^2 + 2xy $$
with:
$$ u_x = 2x + 2y\ \ \  \text{  and }\ \ \ \  u_y = 2x - 2y $$

$$ v_y = u_x \implies v = 2xy + y^2 + C(x) $$

Then:
$$ v_x = -u_y \implies 2y + C'(x) = -2x + 2y \implies C(x) = -x^2 + c $$

Answer (score 1):

Sharply looking at your function, you find that it it $u(x,y)=Re\bigl((1-i)·(x+iy)^2\bigr)$. The PDE are then the Cauchy-Riemann equations and $v$ is the imaginary part, i.e., 
$$
v(x,y)=Im\bigl((1-i)·(x+iy)^2\bigr)=Im\bigl((1-i)(x^2-y^2+2ixy)\bigr)=-(x^2-y^2)+2xy
$$